# How to apply border to every single element in html page?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to find out how can I apply border to every single element in html page?

Html file:

```css
li {}

.hi {}

#name 

* {
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<h1>page site</h1>
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Click Me For Google</a>
<ul>
  <li>Coke</li>
  <li>Tango</li>
  <li>Spite</li>
</ul>
<h3>Beers</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Carling</li>
  <li>Foster</li>
  <li>Budweiser</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why did you include two empty rules and one rule with an ID that isn't in your code?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. When asking a question, you should really show us what you have tried to accomplish what you want, and tell us what specifically wasn't working. Having a read of this might help you get better responses to your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link https://www.lifewire.com/grouping-multiple-css-selectors-3467065

Try this:

```
h1, a, h3, li { border: 2px solid lightgrey; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add a border to every element in the page. However, this doesn't seem very useful.

```
* { border: 1px solid black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head>
<style>



*{
  border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>
<body>
<div>
<h1>page site</h1>
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Click Me For Google</a>
<ul>
  <li>Coke</li>
  <li>Tango</li>
  <li>Spite</li>
</ul>
<h3>Beers</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Carling</li>
  <li>Foster</li>
  <li>Budweiser</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

try to execute this code,it may help u.